# Локальное хранилище в PHP (как в JS - localStorage)

Tags: php, storage

Доброго времени суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в PHP такая же или схожая функция как и в JS - localStorage (где можно хранить данные, текст, массивы)

Не использую SESSION и COOKIE так как создаю Бота для Сообщества во ВКонтакте, и как я уже убедился, ВК не хранит Куки, и из за этого при каждом новом вызове скрипта - новая сессия получается (надеюсь понятно объяснил..)

MySQL не хочу использовать - так как не вижу смысла для такого типа данных (всего массив из 2 ключей и значений), поэтому хотелось бы  что то встроенное из PHP, если есть вообще такая возможность

Comment: Ну тогда просто создавайте файлы, наверное?

Comment: @andreymal , я смогу изменять этот файл, к примеру в том файле будет массив с данными: one => cat, two => dog и мне необходимо удалить two, смогу ли я такое сделать?

Comment: для таких целей используют Redis или что-то аналогичное.

Comment: @ARTURI просто запишите новый файл с нужными данными поверх старого

Comment: @andreymal , боюсь в таком случае, если будет сразу несколько запросов, то будут возможны баги с этим файлом..

Comment: @ARTURI точно такие же баги возможны с SESSION и COOKIE, просто видимо вы их не замечали

Answer (score 0):

Для меня это Новость, но как оказалось, в PHP есть встроенная функция SQLite3 -> это та же mysql, на сколько я понимаю, но к ней не нужно подключаться по сети (она работает локально), это огромный плюс в некоторых случаях, думаю это именно то что я и искал. Отклик должен быть очень быстрым, вроде..)

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: Лайт очень медленная.

Comment: @Red вы просто не умеете её готовить

Comment: @ARTURI при использовании SQLite3 имейте в виду, что «если будет сразу несколько запросов», то при попытке одновременного доступа к базе он может выбросить ошибку наподобие «database is locked», так что вам, вероятно, стоит не забыть потыкать [SQLite3::busyTimeout](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/sqlite3.busytimeout.php)